# Is there any way to estimate the throughput (number of bits proccesed per second) of an application?

Tags: performance, architecture, computer-science, cpu-usage, software-design

I want to estimate the maximum number of bits that can be processed in a second by an application (or we can assume a VM or a container) based on a fixed amount of Memory and CPU assigned to it.

E.g., Consider a VM with fixed 1GB Memory and 1 CPU core (2.4 GHz of clock rate), how many bits it can process per second?

I know that many other factors affect the performance of the application, but I want to reach a rough idea of the impact of these two factors on the overall performance.

Any suggestions for scientific papers would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to perform a theoretical analysis or a practical one? What kind of operation do you want exactly to measure (eg. bit-wise operations, floating-point operations, memory throughput)?

Comment: I'm more interested in theoretical analysis. I want to measure memory throughput, but also would be great if you give a hint for other operations too.